# How to record camera with sound from external source on an iPhone 7?

Tags: iphone, audio, video, airplay, recording

Pretty much what I'm trying to do. I want to record the camera's picture but the sound shouldn't come from the microphone directly but via an external audio signal.

What are my options?

I have either an analog audio signal via a jack cable or using a Windows laptop on the other hand.

The problem is: even though AirServer works on Windows and thus I can see my iPhone's picture on it I can't record audio with it from the PC nor record fullscreen video.

I see that the only way to do this is to buy a Mac and use Quicktime?

What about analog audio to USB going directly into the iPhone, would that work?

Obviously I could edit the two together (video and sound) but I don't want to do that if I can avoid it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole heap of external microphones you can use with the iPhone 7.

**Use the included adapter**

Firstly, the most basic option, is to simply use the Lightning Port > 3.5mm adapter that comes with the phone. This adapter supports [Tip Run Ring Sleeve](https://www.provideocoalition.com/ts-trs-trrs-trrrs-combating-the-misconnection-epidemic/) (TRRS), so you could just plug in an external microphone into the iPhone 7 that way (i.e. an external microphone that supports the TRRS plug).

**Lightning port microphones**

However, if you're looking for a more dedicated solution without an extra adapter in the way, you do have a number of options available if you want to connect directly via the Lightning port. Below are some options for you (ranging in quality, price and features):

- [Sennheiser ClipMic Digital](https://en-au.sennheiser.com/clipmic-digital-mobile-recording)
- [iRig Pro](https://en-au.sennheiser.com/clipmic-digital-mobile-recording)
- [iRig Mic HD](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irigmichd)
- [iRig Field](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irigmicfield/)
- [iRig Pro Duo](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irigproduo/)
- [iRig Mic Studio](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irigmicstudio/)
- [Rode i-XLR](http://www.rode.com/microphones/i-xlr)
- [Shure MV88](http://www.shure.com/americas/products/microphones/motiv/mv88-ios-digital-stereo-condenser-microphone)
- [Zoom iQ5](https://www.zoom.co.jp/products/handy-recorder/iq5-ms-stereo-microphone-ios)
- [Zoom iQ6](https://www.zoom.co.jp/products/handy-recorder/zoom-iq6-professional-stereo-microphone-ios)

**Disclaimer:** I am not affiliated with any of the above products.

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with external mics, but if I use the built in camera app will it record the sound from the external mic? And I'd rather use an external AUDIO signal as I mentioned, not a microphone.

Comment: I am aware of a number of L&D departments that use various external 3.5mm microphones for video capture from iPhones, so it should work fine as I'm not aware that they're using any different camera apps for their video capture. That said, I don't know if any of them have started using iPhone 7 models yet.

Comment: Re wanting to use an external audio signal, sorry, I interpreted your question as meaning an external microphone. You may need to clarify the question somewhat.

Comment: Well something like a guitar or synth output so I can record the guitar while recording the guitar with the camera. That kind of stuff. I know there are devices like iRig for this but I don't know if they work with the camera together, or how I'd do this. Sounds like a simple problem yet I don't find a solution which does not involve multiple devices and video editing.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, I know some L&D departments that have used iPhones for filming video and they use external microphones plugged into the 3.5mm socket. As far as I'm aware, the iPhone just recognises that an external microphone is being used while they're using the default camera for video recording. I would suggest contacting support for a couple of the options that interest you, and ask them the question. There may even be some FAQs on their website.

Comment: Also, here is [one](https://youtu.be/a_C2Szag4ko) example (albeit a cheap one) that shows it will work with the camera.

Comment: Yeah this was simple with iPhone 6 and before, but now they removed the small jack too. So essentially I was trying to do this without an external device, but I think I need something like iRig 2. I guess I'll have to ask them about the video part. Thanks for the reply