# How can I use a Steinberg UR22 audio card for audio while recording video with an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, camera, video-capture

My need is to record video while using a Steinberg UR22 audio card to feed in the audio signal, via the lightning cable.

At the moment, the default Camera application is not recognizing/picking-up the audio signal when recording (the video stream is recorded, but not the audio).

That connection works out for the Youtube application, since that application is recording both video and "external" audio. I can stream live with the YouTube app on iPhone, and the audio-card is recognized as a viable audio source. So the hardware side of things seems to be ok.

PS: There are similar questions out there, but these use an external microphone. Whereas I am trying to feed in the sound via an "usb-to-lightning" Apple original cable, which is considered by Steinberg card manufacturer as a standard method to connect an iPhone/iPad to the sound card.

PPS: iPhone X, latest OS version/patches, original lightning and adapter from Apple, Steinberg UR22 sound card (with iOS support per manufacturer).

Comment: [iPhone App for External Microphone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373292/iphone-app-for-external-microphone) and [How to record camera with sound from external source on an iPhone 7?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286173/how-to-record-camera-with-sound-from-external-source-on-an-iphone-7) Hope the votes on your meta post didn't discourage you :)